# Using Blender's Python API to get parent bone names

Tags: python, bones, parent

I’m trying to write a script that will change the name of a parent bone. However digging for data I’m not getting what I suspected to get. I realize that to change data I will have to do it through Edit_Bones not data.bones, I’m just searching for names at this point.

My code currently looks like this:

```
  bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode="OBJECT")
     for ob in bpy.data.objects:
        if ob.type == "ARMATURE" and ob.users !=0:
            for bone in ob.data.bones:
                print('%s, %s' %(bone.name, bone.parent))
```

What it returns look like this:

> pelvis, None
>
> spine_01, <"bpy_struct, Bone("pelvis")>
>
> spine_02, <"bpy_struct, Bone("spine_01")>
>
> spine_03, <"bpy_struct, Bone("spine_02")>
>
> spine_04, <"bpy_struct, Bone("spine_03")>

The return is correct, but I want to be able to just return the parent bone name and be able to change it to something else.

If I try to use `bone.parent.name` the script errors out on the Root (Pelvis) Bone with a NoneType Error.

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "C:\Users\ME\Desktop\PKTEST\Clown_REdo.blend\toTxt_BoneRolls.py", line
>   41, in  AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute
>   'name' Error: Python script fail, look in the console for now...

How would I get just the Parent name (Right side of the comma) for the bone on the left?

Comment: A parent value of `None` indicates no parent bone.  Something like `getattr(bone.parent, "name", "None")` will return "None" if the `bone.parent is None`.

Comment: batFinger you are great at answering these things. In fact, I think you're batting 98% of or all my questions asked. (lol)

Comment: The getattr() returns what I'm looking for , but  how would I update this. I use a dictionary and code like 'code'  bones = bpy.context.selected_objects[0].data.bones

if (bones):
    for bone in bones:
        newName = names.get(bone.name)
        if (newName):
            bone.name = newname 'code'

Comment: That is the code I use for renaming bones. Not what I would use in this case or parents, or would it work if I switch to edit_bones and a code like if (newName): bone.parent.name = newname

Comment: and for gawd sake, answer the question so I can credit you!!!  lol

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since parent as a property is always present (being either an object or None and objects always have a name) you can make a ternary conditional inside the print since it's the second access that causes issues not the first (accessing the parent's name not accesing the parent itself).

```
print('%s, %s' %(bone.name, bone.parent.name if bone.parent else "No Parent"))
```

When updating the property, similarly you can simply check or place it inside a try/except block:

```
if bone.parent:
     bone.parent.name = ""
```

or

```
try:
     bone.parent.name = ""
except:
     pass
```